# Back-up -14.04 LTS and auto upgrade to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, backup, lts

I was running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit and stupidly agreed to an auto-upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when prompted on an update. I did not back-up - I know - stupid, please be gentle. Linux novice

The auto-upgrade for some reason decided to install a 32 bit version. I did not ask it to do this. I now wish to upgrade to 16.04 LTS 64-bit. In order to do this I need to back up. I am having issues doing this and I suspect that it might be a conflict between the 14.04 LTS 64-bit generated files I have and the 16.04 LTS 32-bit OS I am now running.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem and if so any suggested solutions? Does anyone know if any of the back up software out there is indifferent to OS/file architecture (I am guessing not).

Comment: Instead of installing software on the OS as it is, you could boot a live disc to do the backup.